# Snowflake COPY INTO specific columns - How to do it

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

How to use COPY INTO command to insert data to specific columns of a table

table name: `tblUser`

```
columns & type:
     myNo VARCHAR
     myName VARCHAR
    myAddress VARCHAR
     myStatus VARCHAR
     dateTimeStamp DATETIME
     InsertedBy VARCHAR
```

I have a working query:

```
     SELECT json_data:myNo
      ,json_data:"myName"::VARCHAR
    ,json_data:"myAddress"::VARCHAR
    ,json_data:"myStatus"::VARCHAR
    ,current_timestamp
    ,current_user 
       
     FROM(
        SELECT PARSE_JSON($1) AS json_data
        FROM @STAGE_BASE/SUBDIR/sample_data_file.json
        (FILE_FORMAT => JSON_FORMAT)
    );
```

I cannot make it work for some reason.

I have tried the copy into with columns...followed by the query...
I am getting some syntax wrong perhaps as it complains about the `SELECT` keyword.
What correction is needed?

Comment: Please update your question with the "COPY INTO with columns" statement that you are using and the actual error message you are getting

Comment: What is the name of your actual stage? Can you provide your file_format definition, it may be helpful? I'm not sure if you are just loading a `VARIANT` (json blob) or converting it prior to attempting the `COPY INTO`.

Answer (score 1):

[COPY INTO table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table) supports two types:

> /* Standard data load */
>
> ```
> COPY INTO [<namespace>.]<table_name>
>      FROM { internalStage | externalStage | externalLocation }
> [ FILES = ( '<file_name>' [ , '<file_name>' ] [ , ... ] ) ]
> [ PATTERN = '<regex_pattern>' ]
> [ FILE_FORMAT = ( { FORMAT_NAME = '[<namespace>.]<file_format_name>' |
>                     TYPE = { CSV | JSON | AVRO | ORC | PARQUET | XML } [ formatTypeOptions ] } ) ]
> [ copyOptions ]
> [ VALIDATION_MODE = RETURN_<n>_ROWS | RETURN_ERRORS | RETURN_ALL_ERRORS ]
> ```

> /* Data load with transformation */
>
> ```
> COPY INTO [<namespace>.]<table_name> [ ( <col_name> [ , <col_name> ... ] ) ]
>      FROM ( SELECT [<alias>.]$<file_col_num>[.<element>] [ , [<alias>.]$<file_col_num>[.<element>] ... ]
>             FROM { internalStage | externalStage } )
> [ FILES = ( '<file_name>' [ , '<file_name>' ] [ , ... ] ) ]
> [ PATTERN = '<regex_pattern>' ]
> [ FILE_FORMAT = ( { FORMAT_NAME = '[<namespace>.]<file_format_name>' |
>                     TYPE = { CSV | JSON | AVRO | ORC | PARQUET | XML } [ formatTypeOptions ] } ) ]
> [ copyOptions ]
> ```

---

[Transforming Data During a Load](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform)

> The COPY command supports:
>
> - **Column reordering**, column omission, and casts using a SELECT statement. There is no requirement for your data files to have the same number and ordering of columns as your target table.
> - The ENFORCE_LENGTH | TRUNCATECOLUMNS option, which can truncate text strings that exceed the target column length.

Example:

[Reorder CSV Columns During a Load](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform#reorder-csv-columns-during-a-load)

> ```
> copy into home_sales(city, zip, sale_date, price)
> from (select SUBSTR(t.$2,4), t.$1, t.$5, t.$4 from @mystage t)
> FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = mycsvformat);
> ```